# How to get the Value of a Dropdownlist in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html.dropdownlistfor

This is a really simple problem I can't figure out.  I am trying to get the value of a dropdownlist using Javascript.  I have 4 digit job codes in my dropdownlist.  On a button click I got to this function and am trying to get the value of what was selected when a button was pushed.

```
 function jobCodeToAdd() {

 var jobCode = document.getElementById("<%=jobCode.ClientID%>"));
 var selectedJobCode = jobCode.options[jobCode.selectedIndex].value;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does your html look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `.text`

```
 var jobCode = document.getElementById("<%=jobCode.ClientID%>"));
 var selectedJobCode = jobCode.options[jobCode.selectedIndex].text;
```